# How can I translate an Image to the point where there are no pixel differences?

Tags: java, image

I'm working on an image project that requires a specific method called "translate" to same some time here is a description of the method and a visual demonstration.

Description:
In this method you should create a new image whose pixel coordinates have been shifted in the xdimension by an offset of dx pixels, and shifted in the y dimension by an offset of dy pixels, relative to those in the source image (dx and dy are provided as parameters). For example, if dx is 2 and dy is -1, the pixels of the source are moved by 2px to the right (positive x) and 1px upward (negative y). The resulting image is the same size as the source image. For example, if the 6x4 image below were moved by dx=2 and dy=1, the pixel at (x=2, y=3) labeled as "U" would move to (x=4, y=2).

If shifting a pixel causes it to pass the edge of the image, "wrap" that pixel around to the opposite side of the image (think of the image as an infinite canvas that "wraps around" on itself in all directions). For example, if dx is 2 and dy is -1, the pixel at (x=5, y=2) labeled as "R" above would normally have shifted to (x=7, y=1), but x=7 is off the edge, so we wrap it around to (x=1, y=1) in the result. Similarly, "D" at (3, 0) moves to (5, 3). The dx and/or dy might be negative or larger than the overall size of the image. In the example above, translating by a dx of 8, or 14, or 320, or -4, or -6004, etc., would yield the same result as translating by a dx of 2.

[image]

[image]

Now here is my real problem, I have written what I believed to be the solution to this algorithm but for some reason I am getting a large pixel difference when comparing the correct image. In which I am unsure what manipulating variable is needed to be modified or removed in order for the pixel differences to be solved. Here is my code below:

```java
public GImage translate(GImage source, int dx, int dy) {
        int[][] pixel = source.getPixelArray();
        int width = pixel.length;
        int height = pixel[0].length;
        int[][] translate = new int[width][height];

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                int newX = (x - dx + width) % width;
                int newY = (y - dy + height) % height;

                translate[x][y] = pixel[newX][newY];
            }
        }

        GImage image = new GImage(translate);
        return image;
    }
```

Output (dx = 100 , dy = 50)

[image]

Comment: Looking at the example, is the new location created by adding the offset, or subtracting it? What does your code do?